# Is there a way to get cumulative percentages in PHP?

Tags: php

I want to run cumulative percentages. I can do it for my array in R as follows:

```r
df<- data.frame( x= c(6,8,9,8,9,8,5,4,4,9))


df %>% 
    count(x) %>% 
    mutate(cum=cumsum(n)/sum(n)) %>%
    complete(x = seq(min(x), max(x)), fill = list(n = 0)) %>%
    fill(cum)
```

and I get the results:

```
A tibble: 6 x 3
      x     n   cum
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     4     2   0.2
2     5     1   0.3
3     6     1   0.4
4     7     0   0.4
5     8     3   0.7
6     9     3   1
```

As you can see, I get the value of 7 as well using this code.

I want to get the same output using PHP.

I have written this code so far to get frequency, but as you can see the value 7 has not appeared.

I want to get cumulative percentages (cum) which I was unable to do. The code that I have used is:

```php
<?php
$array = array(6,8,9,8,9,8,5,4,4,9);
function Counting($array){
    return(array_count_values($array));    
}

print_r(Counting($array)); 

?>
```

Comment: Just for trying to understand this math.. How do get 0.2 in the first row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`array_count_values` would give you just the frequency of elements. To find out cumulative, you would have to do the addition yourself.

```
<?php 
$array = array(6,8,9,8,9,8,5,4,4,9);
function Counting($array){ 
    $freq_data = array_count_values($array);
    $unique_elements = array_map('intval',array_keys($freq_data));
    sort($unique_elements);
    $percentage_data = [];
    $total = count($array);
    foreach($unique_elements as $index => $element){
        $current_percentage = $freq_data[$element] / $total;
        $percentage_data[$element] = $index > 0 ?  $percentage_data[$prev_element] +  $current_percentage : $current_percentage;
        $prev_element = $element;
    }
    return $percentage_data;
} 

print_r(Counting($array));
```

**Demo:** https://3v4l.org/vodsf

---

**Update:**

Since you need all the missing elements between min and max elements, you can just loop over the frequency data and have an `isset` check to gather the cumulatives for missing as well as non missing.

```
<?php 
$array = array(6,8,9,8,9,8,5,4,4,9);
function Counting($array){ 
    $freq_data = array_count_values($array);
    $unique_elements = array_map('intval',array_keys($freq_data));

    $min_element = min($unique_elements);
    $max_element = max($unique_elements);

    $percentage_data = [];
    $total = count($array);

    for($i = $min_element; $i <= $max_element ; ++$i){
        $current_percentage = isset($freq_data[$i]) ? ($freq_data[$i] / $total) : 0;
        $percentage_data[$i] = $i > $min_element ?  $percentage_data[$i-1] +  $current_percentage : $current_percentage;
    }

    uksort($percentage_data,function($a,$b){
        return strnatcmp($a,$b);
    });// just to be sure that associative hash keys are in ascending order

    return $percentage_data;
} 

print_r(Counting($array));
```

**Demo:** https://3v4l.org/41g2n

Comment: @user1946911 Is it like all the missing bits between lowest value and highest value?

Comment: That's correct. So we need to have  all the lowest and the highest values

Comment: @user1946911 Glad I could help :)